# Matrix not rotating 90 degree to Right

Tags: java, matrix

**I want to rotate matrix 90 degree to right, using a single dimension array but it does not give the desired output**

I used a simple method before and it did work, so for practice i tried to do it with the help of a single dimension array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class nine
{
    void main()
    {
        int M, i ,j;
        int z=0;
        int arr[][], x[];

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER THE NUMBER OF ROW AND COLUMN OF MATRIX");
        M=sc.nextInt();

        arr=new int[M][M];
        x=new int[M*M];
        System.out.println("ENTER THE ELEMENTS IN MATRIX ");
        for(i=0;i< M;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j< M;j++)
            {
                arr[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println( );
        System.out.println( "------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("ORIGINAL MATRIX \n");
        for(i=0;i< M;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j< M;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println( );
        System.out.println( "------------------------------------------------------");
        
        /* giving matrix x the value of arr from bottom. 
         * example matrix-
            1 2 3 
            4 5 6 
            7 8 9 
            value stored in x- {7 8 9 4 5 6 3 2 1}
        */
        for(i=M-1;i>0;i--)
        {
            for(j=0;j< M;j++)
            {
                x[z]=arr[i][j];
                z++;
            }
        }
        z=0; 
        /* 
         * Adding values of matrix x in matrix arr veritcally. 
         * 
           */
        for(j=0;j< M;j++)
        {
            for(i=0;i< M;i++)
            {
                arr[i][j]= x[z];
                z++;
            }
        }
         /* 
         * Desired output from the example input- 
         *      7 4 1 
                8 5 2 
                9 6 3 
         * 
           */
        System.out.println("ROTATED MATRIX \n");
        for(i=0;i< M;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j< M;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" " );

            }
            System.out.println( );
        }
    }
}
```

---

The original array is double dimension and  gives value to the single dimension array in the order stated.

**The output I want is :**

[image: img1]

**The output I am getting is is :**

[image: img2]

Comment: You haven't' write anything to `x`, but you read the value from `x` (which are all `0`) and write to `arr`

Comment: After displaying the original matrix, I had x have values.

Comment: Read your own code again. you write `arr[i][j]= x[z];` before you have written anything to `x`. `x[z]` are always `0` here. So you are just throwing values in `arr` away. You know you did something wrong here. You probably want `x[z] = arr[i][j]` instead

Comment: Also note that this loop does not loop through the whole matrix because you write it loop from `M-1` to `1`(`i>0`). This might also be a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the change in `arr[i][j]= x[z];`. I edited the question as still i am facing problem in the output

Comment: change `for(i=M-1;i>0;i--)` to `for(i=M-1;i>=0;i--)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*turning the comment by Ricky Mo into an answer with minimal changes and explanation*)

You are very close. No need to fundamentally change your approach.
However, the output you get shows clearly that your code does not write to the last column.
An obvious conclusion is that your loop setups are not correct.
And indeed (as Ricky Mo put succinctly):

> change `for(i=M-1;i>0;i--)` to `for(i=M-1;i>=0;i--)`

Obviously it iterates once more often.
And that ends up in the right (i.e. the 0 values column) because of the indexing magic, which you correctly implemented.

And the output is:

```
ENTER THE NUMBER OF ROW AND COLUMN OF MATRIX
ENTER THE ELEMENTS IN MATRIX 

------------------------------------------------------
ORIGINAL MATRIX 

1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 

------------------------------------------------------
ROTATED MATRIX 

7 4 1 
8 5 2 
9 6 3
```

e.g. here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

Answer (score 1):

To rotate, you need something like this:

```
int arr[][];
int dest[][];

arr = new int[M][M];
dest = new int[M][M];

for (int i=0; i<M, i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<M, j++) {
    dest[M-j-1][i] = arr[i][j];
  }
}
```

also, you count down loops need to include zero

```
for(i=M-1;i>0;i--)
```

should be

```
for(i=M-1;i>=0;i--)
```

Comment: "you need this" and then you show a different solution. That confuses me.